# Getting values with javascript position()

Tags: javascript, html

My shopping cart script is intended to check if an article is already in the shopping cart; then the numbers must be filled in the survey.

I work with Javascript. I give the ID number through a `position()` function.

This is a part of the script where I pick list:

```
<input type="text" size="2" name="aantalArts_{position()}" id="aantalArts_{position()}"/>
```

The output:

```
<input type="text" size="2" value="" name="aantalArts_1" id="test" class="infoButton">
<input type="text" size="2" value="" name="aantalArts_2" id="test" class="infoButton">
<input type="text" size="2" value="" name="aantalArts_3" id="test" class="infoButton">
<input type="text" size="2" value="" name="aantalArts_4" id="test" class="infoButton">
```

I am just filling the numbers, but how do I deal with the positions?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    if(document.all.artNr.value = <%=artNrWW%>);{
        document.all.aantalArts_??????.value = <%=aantalWW%>;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what do you want to do, as it's very clear (where's the shopping cart? what survey?). Also, you have an extra `;` between the if and the brace.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the following syntax:

```
var i = 1; // or whichever
document.all["aantalArts_" + i].value = <% aantalWW %>;
```